# How to contribute to ROS2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I m planning to contribute to ros2, but I m a bit confused, the ros2 contributing  guildlines tells us that, we need to build it from source (I have done this), but now how do I do version control from this workspace, the correct way to contribute to any open source is by by forking that repo, then creating branch for each issue, but I m not getting how all this is achievable from ros2 workspace which is built by source.

The workspace doesnt contain .git folder so I need to first do `git init`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372184/how-to-contribute-to-ros2/) by [suab123](https://answers.ros.org/users/44652/suab123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2021-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Welcome! Thanks for your interest in contributing to ROS 2.

These instructions:
https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Development-Setup/#get-ros-2-code

Will use the `vcs` tool to automate the cloning of a bunch of `git` repos to the `~/ros2_foxy/src` directory. Specifically, these ones:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/foxy/ros2.repos

It's the same normal open-source process on GitHub, just that `vcs` is doing one more step of automation because there are so many repos that it would be painful to clone them all one-by-one using `git` on the command line.

Whenever you want to change something in any of those `git` clones created by `vcs`, you can fork the respective upstream repository into your own GitHub account, and push your local changes into your personal fork, as normal, and create PR's back to upstream.

---

Originally posted by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) with karma: 521 on 2021-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [suab123](https://answers.ros.org/users/44652/suab123/) on 2021-02-19**:
thanks for the answers, prev I had built foxy, but someone told me build on this instead https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/master/ros2.repos all this is done :)

What you said forking appropriate repo and then work on it, but then I how do I check if my changes compille or not, prev what I used to do is, suppose I making change in rclcpy then I will copy rclpy to work space(build from source) and then run colcon build to check if my changes are compiling, but this process is a bit tedious.

Also is the build type of source Debug build for rclcpp (or any c++ code repos).

**Comment by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) on 2021-02-19**:
Ah, yeah, if you're wanting to work on the leading-edge stuff and make PR's back to the `main`/`master` branches of the upstream repos, you're correct, you'll need to use a repo list that has all of the `main` / `master` branches in it, not the `foxy` branches. My mistake.

The contributing guide here should be exhaustive and up-to-date:
https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Contributing/#contributing-code

There is no need to be copying code between various places in your filesystem every change; you can set up your workspace to have your own forks in it. Then you can just edit-in-place and compile (typically in separate terminals, just for convenience). Usually you only want to work on a small number (like 1 or 2) of the many repos that `vcs` will clone for you, so you can just let the "full" `vcs` clone finish, then go in by hand and point the 1 or 2 repos you want to your own personal forks and `git pull` them. I'm not a `git` expert by any means, but that works for me.

**Comment by [suab123](https://answers.ros.org/users/44652/suab123/) on 2021-02-19**:
okay this will seem to solve the problem, thanks for the help

Also do you know if Debug build is build from default when we build  workspace with colcon?